# Write string to a .txt file, FileOutputStream is not working as expected

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream

I have an app and I want to create a text file and write something in it. I use explicit intent to select folder and create file, where mimeType=text/plain

```
 private void createFile(String mimeType, String fileName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType(mimeType);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, fileName);
    startActivityForResult(intent, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

after creating the file I use onActivityResult to write to it

```
if (requestCode == WRITE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = resultData.getData();
        String path = uri.getPath();
        File file = new File(path);
        String filename = file.getName();
        try {
            verifyStoragePermissions(this); //method to access storage
            FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput(filename,MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write("Message to write".getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I also have permitions in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I don't get an error but there is nothing written in my file. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` gives you a `Uri` to use for writing content to. **A `Uri` is not a file**.
2. `openFileOutput()` is for internal storage, not external storage, and so the permissions are pointless
3. `openFileOutput()` has nothing to do with `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`
4. Do not write strings via `getBytes()`

Tactically, replace your second code block with this:

```
if (requestCode == WRITE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    Uri uri = resultData.getData();

    try {
        OutputStream os=getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
        PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(os);
        ps.print("Message to write");
        ps.flush();
        ps.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Some identifying string", "Exception writing to "+uri.toString(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do I have to change to save this as an .xml file? I already changed mimeType but does not work

Comment: @IoannaDln: I do not know what you mean by "save this as an .xml file", sorry. If you are asking how to ask the user for a location for an XML file, I would expect a MIME type of `text/xml` would help, though there is no requirement for the user to stick with any particular file extension.

Comment: instead of creating a .txt file I want to create an .xml file but I get empty files with no data written

Comment: @IoannaDln: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] showing what you are trying and explaining, in detail, how are you determining that you "get empty files with no data written".